# Regex for fixed length string, starting with multiple words

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regex (JS flavor) that matches a string that is exactly 17 alphanumeric characters in length and must start with either "AB, "DE" or "GH". After these 3 possibilities, any alphanumeric character is accepted.

Match:

```
AB163829F13246915
DET639601BA167860
GHF1973771A002957
```

Don't match

```
XYZ63829F13246915
AAA639601BA167860
BBC1973771A002957
```

So far I have this regex which I'm testing on http://regexpal.com/

```
^(AB|)[a-zA-Z0-9]{17}$
```

Not sure why the pipe character is required for it to match my first example, or why it fails when I add "DE" after the pipe.

Anyone?

Comment: Are you trying to capture the first two words?  If not you could use `[ABDEGH]`.

Comment: Can the `AB`, `DE`, `GH` parts be lower case as well?

Comment: I used this web-tool and really liked it https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use this:

```
^(AB|DE|GH)[a-zA-Z0-9]{15}$
```

The first two characters already take up two, so you only need 15 more alphanumeric characters after that.

http://rubular.com/r/rAWmIy4Xeh

Answer (score 6):

You had it almost:

```
(AB|DE|GH)[a-zA-Z0-9]{15}
```

[Demo](http://www.debuggex.com/r/9Ougew_7FK5HlgcK/0)

Since `AB|DE|GH` will already be 2-char long, only 15 must be allowed beyond.

You can also use a non-capturing group (`(?:AB|DE|GH)[a-zA-Z0-9]{15}`) and anchor your pattern (`^(?:AB|DE|GH)[a-zA-Z0-9]{15}$`) if needed.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
/^(?:AB|DE|GH)[A-Z0-9]{15}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current regex is looking for a string that may or may not start with `AB`, followed by some alphanumeric characters. If it does start with `AB`, the string length will be 19. Otherwise, it's 17.

Clearly, this is not what you meant.

Try this:

```
/^(?=AB|DE|GH)[a-zA-Z0-9]{17}$/
```

This uses a lookahead assertion to ensure the string starts with the right combinaions, then effectively starts over as it counts out the 17 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
^(AB|DE|GH)[a-zA-Z0-9]{15}$
```

Whatever is matched by `(AB|DE|GH)` will consume exactly two characters, so you need to change the repetition on the `[a-zA-Z0-9]` character class to 15.

Note that this can also be shortened a bit:

```
^(AB|DE|GH)[^\W_]{15}$
```

This works because `\W` matches everything except letters, numbers, and underscores.  Putting `\W` and `_` in a negated character class gives you an element that will only match letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern, the pipe makes the first part of it matches either `AB` or an empty string. You haven't excluded the two characters from the 17, so it has to match the empty string to get the next 17 characters to match the rest of the pattern. The pattern will also match for example `AB00000000000000000`, i.e. `AB` followed by 17 alphanumerics.

You should make it match the combinations of two characters at the start, then 15 alphanumeric characters:

```
^(AB|DE|GH)[a-zA-Z0-9]{15}$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below restriction in xsd for alphamuneric string with fixed length.

```
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}" />
```